# LinkedIn Access Token Being Used

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api, api-key

I've successfully secured my access token for the LinkedIn API. However, when I try to use it to gather user information (currently just my own so I know that the profile has all public settings) using this code:

```
requestURL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{my_linkedin_id})'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ' ' + access_token}
a = requests.get(requestURL,headers=headers)
```

could someone elaborate on any steps I might be messing?

When I run this code I keep getting a

```
<Response [404]>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have 404 as response and in [LinkedIn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/error-handling#404-resource-not-found) you can see that:

> 404 Resource Not Found
>
> This error occurs when your application tries to call an API or fetch
> an entity that does not exist. For example, the API to get a friend’s
> profile is /v2/people/id={personId}, not /v2/person/id={personId}. In
> some cases (Ads, for example), a 404 error is returned when attempting
> to access a restricted API. See 403 Access Denied and contact your
> partner technical support channel if you continue to see the error.

I think you need too check if your link to resource is good.